# New Badge Idea: Specialist badge

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Right now, there's a silver badge for "Generalist" (Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags)...  I'd propose a new "Specialist" badge with the meaning:

```
Reputation of at least 10,000 and more than 75% of reputation from a single tag
```

It would likely be a gold badge since the rep count required is quite high (but there could be a silver equivalent)...

Comment: Are you aware of the [tag badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags)?  They serve a similar purpose.

Comment: @Popular They serve such a similar purpose that they're also referred to as [specialist badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specialist).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Badges are meant to encourage positive behaviour.

We already have [tag-based](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) badges which reward you for work in *any* particular tag.

What is the benefit of encouraging users to work *only* in that tag?

Comment: A lot of people do that anyway....

Comment: @skaffman At which point we would be encouraging them to... stay the course?

Comment: Fair enough...  Good points.

Comment: The OP might have intended it as a sort of "consolation" badge, much like the Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges (which I always thought were a bad idea).

Comment: @Ether Any badge with the "%" in the criteria will suffer from largely the same issues.

Comment: I only see three sentences. Where is the rest of your answer? :P

Comment: @Jon I'm branching out.

Comment: @JonB Guess devin's not cut out to be El Duderino.

Comment: @Grace, yeah, he appears to be getting into that whole "brevity" thing. :)